# How to suppress proxychains message

Tags: proxy, output, message, suppress

Note: this question is about proxychains not proxychains-ng.

By default, proxychains output some message like the below. How can suppress this message?

`ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)`

Answer (score 7):

Use sed to cut off first line

```
proxychains | sed -n '2,$p'
```

or upgrade to proxychain4

```
proxychains -q
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write `quiet_mode` in your `/etc/proxychains(4).conf` file.

It may already be there commented, therefore just remove `#` before it.